# PHP max_execution_time shows but not works

Tags: php

I set `max_execution_time` for my php engine (below you can see `phpinfo()` output on my host) but it seems not working for my following code:

## phinfo() :

```
                     Local value     Master value
                    -------------    ------------    
max_execution_time       5                 5
```

---

## My PHP code :

```
<?php 
$start=time();
$x=0;
while($x<10) {
   $x++;
   echo time() - $start;
   echo '<br/>';
```

### }

## Code Output:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
......

---

It should endup when after 5 seconds of execution( due to `max_execution_time`) but it doesn't time out even after 20 seconds,then I stop it manually.
How would i solve this problem?( my `max_time_execution` setting is not working

Comment: in short, sleep is not counted, only actual running execution time is.

Comment: I noted that when i remove `sleep`, it doesn' change and code does not terminate on timeout! so `sleep` is not problem.